# How to get credentials User/password after JWT Authentification

Tags: php, database, authentication, jwt

In my application i want (need) to authentificate users the following way.

The credentials „user“, „password“ are submitted to a php script. This script checks if a connection to a sql database with this credentials is successfull. When successfull a jwt is generated and  the user is logged in a vue js application. This step works fine.

In the application when i do database inserts, updates etc. i need to make these requests with the credentials of the user because when the db tables get updated the userName is automatically inserted in a table column „user_name“ which is a requirement for the whole app.

I know that it is not secure to store the credentials in the jwt payload.

Because i‘m not an expert in web development i‘m asking for a good/secure solution/hint to get this done. Maybe it‘s possible to store the credentials hashed in the payload and decrypt on each request.

Comment: You should store the user's id, username, email or any other NON-sensitive detail in the JWT, that will enable the correct database requests for that user to be made. NEVER put a password or any other sensitive information like an API key etc. in a JWT. You can decode the JWT and get these credentials later. You will never need to get your password, so you don't have to worry about retrieving it. A site like [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)  can help you know what's in a token you have created. be careful not to store too many things in a JWT, though.

Comment: The problem is i need to make the db update with credentials of the user. So i also need the password to make the connection to the database. The username and password for the webapp are the same as for the database.

Comment: Utilising the same username and password for the web app, to authenticate into the database, is not the best or securest of ideas. You should be using the JWT tokens to authenticate the user based on that token, and (for example) then provide access to the database layer through a DAO (or API).

Comment: The connection to the database should be saved on the server using an environemnt variable. You use a `.env` file in your app for development and you put that file in a `.gitignore` file so that it doesn't get pushed to the git repository (Github, Bitbucket, Gitlab etc.). In production, the environmental variable is specified in the server config. I want to repeat that you NEVER need your password for any web operation.

Comment: The problem is i have to use the credentials for the DB. The Database is also used in an older Windows Application where the login is also made with the DB Credentials. And every table in the DB has a column with the last user as a data type ( http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/current-user-wsqlref.html ). When a row is inserted or updated this column is updated with username of the db connection so i have to make the connection to the db with the explicit user credentials in my webapp as well.

Comment: As you said, crypt with long key in server side and send to client. Decrypt when second request come.